# object.innerHTML not updating properly?

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I tried to make a progress bar in javascript, but it didnt load till my 
program was finished. How can i make it updating while the program is still running?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" onclick="my()">1</div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">start</button>
    <script>
       function myFunction() {
         for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=i;
         }
       }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `setInterval` instead of for cicle and i used `parseInt()` to get integer value of your div innerHTML and then increment it

`setInterval(myFunction, 1000)` runs `myFunction()` every 1000 milliseconds

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" onclick="my()">1</div>
    <button onclick="setInterval(myFunction, 1000)">start</button>
    <script>
       function myFunction(){
            var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("main").innerHTML);
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=value+1;
         }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method which runs in the background without blocking. Once reached the condition you can clear the interval using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) method.

```
function myFunction() {
  // get element reference and cache in a variable
  let main = document.getElementById("main"),
    // initialize i as 0
    i = 0;
  // keep interval reference for clearing once i reached 1000000
  let intrvl = setInterval(() => {
    // check value of i and increment, if reached 1000000 clear the interval
    if (i++ === 1000000) clearInterval(intrvl);
    // update the content of main element
    main.innerHTML = i;
  }, 1000); // set required delay in millisecond, any value lesser than 10 will be automatically converts to 10
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" onclick="my()">1</div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">start</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      let main = document.getElementById("main"),
        i = 0;
      let intrvl = setInterval(() => {
        if (i++ === 1000000) clearInterval(intrvl);
        main.innerHTML = i;
      },1000);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```